# Linq to sql select new string

Tags: c#, .net, linq

So i got this code:

```
ClassA { List<ClassB> classBList;}
ClassB { List<ClassC> classCList;}
ClassC { String ID;}

Dictionary<string,int> dict;
ClassA MyObject;
```

The keys on the dictionary should match the the ID field on ClassC
And i wanna do the following query on linq

```
List<String> matches = (from b in MyObject
                      from c in b.classCList
                      join d in dict
                      on c.ID equals dict.Key
                      select new
                      {
                          c.Value == 0 ? "YES" : "NO"
                      }).ToList();
```

But I'm getting the error: `"Invalid anonymous type member ..."`

The bottomline is ... how can i have a condition within the select new?

**EDIT**

How can i do this query with extended methods?

Any help?
Ty

Comment: You haven't given the member a name.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are trying to select an anonymous type and then you are trying to assign the result back to `List<string>`. Your query should be:

```
List<String> matches = (from b in MyObject.classBList
                        from c in b.classCList
                        join d in dict
                        on c.ID equals d.Key
                        select d.Value == 0 ? "YES" : "NO").ToList();
```

Comment: Ok... I'm feeling really dumb xD Ty :D

Comment: @HélderGonçalves, no worries, happens to all of us :)

Comment: @HélderGonçalves: In addition, CodeCaster's comment holds as well, there is _no_ valid type for matches as you didn't provide a name for the member of the anonymous class you were creating.

Comment: Can you show me how to do that with extended methods from linq? like .Join() :D Ty